# Magento caninvoice always return false

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

```
  if (!$this->_current_order->canInvoice()) {
         $this->Msg[] = 'Can not create Invoice';
         return false;
  }
```

This always returns false.I am not able to create invoice or shipping because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the order is canceled, in complete/closed state.

Maybe its held or still in payment review.

Maybe of the items has no quantity to invoice > 0 or an item is locked to invoice...

I would recomend to put a log in each of the IF-Statements in the method shown below in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

```
    /**
     * Retrieve order invoice availability
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canInvoice()
    {
        if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
            return false;
        }
        $state = $this->getState();
        if ($this->isCanceled() || $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE || $state === self::STATE_CLOSED) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()>0 && !$item->getLockedDoInvoice()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```